# Paypal is it possible to fully automate the Express Checkout flow for unit testing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

According to the specs the Express Checkout flow is like this:

1. SetExpressCheckout
2. Redirect user to login and approve the transaction
3. GetExpressCheckoutDetails
4. DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Is it possible to fully automate step 2 so the complete transaction flow can be unit tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't. Once you redirect, you will need to login with your PayPal credentials to proceed to next step which could not be done automatically.

Comment: That's not strictly true, you could use a tool like selenium webdriver to drive the browser and complete this step. However this will be fragile as it will be tied to the markup on the paypal page.